# Probability of two random n-digit numbers dividing each other

Tags: probability, number-theory, limits, divisibility

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Suppose $a$ and $b$ are randomly (and independently) chosen two $n$-digit positive integers which consist of digits 1, 2, 3, ..., 9. (So in particular neither $a$ nor $b$ contains digit 0; I am adding this condition so that division by $b$ will be possible, and that we don't get numbers of the form $0002$ and so on). Here "randomly" means each digit of $a$ and $b$ is equally likely to be one of the 9 digits from $\{1,2,3,..., 9\}$.

My question concerns the divisibility of these integers:

> 1) What is the probability that $b$ divides $a$ ?

The answer, of course, will depend on $n$. Denote this probability by $p(n)$. I would be happy with rough estimates for $p(n)$ as well :)

> 2) Is it true that $p(n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$?

I think answer to question 2) is yes (just by intuition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $a,b$ are $n$-digit numbers, we have $10^{n-1}\le a,b<10^n$. If $b|a$, this implies $\frac ab\in\{1,2,\ldots,9\}$. So at most $9$ of the $9^n$ possible $b$ are divisors of $a$. $p(n)\le \frac 9{9^n}$.
While this estimate is far from sharp, it shows $p(n)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Can we calculate $p(n)$ more precisely? Your forbidding zeroes is partly making this *more* difficult as divisibility of $a$ by small numbers $\in\{1,2,\ldots,9\}$ becomes less easily predictable.
We need to calculate, for $d\in\{1,\ldots,9\}$, the probability that $a$ is both a multiple of $d$ and is $\ge d\cdot 111\ldots1$ (where $111\ldots1$ is the smallest $n$-digit number without zeroes) and $\frac ad$ has no zeroes.
The probability that $a\ge d\cdot 111\ldots 1$ is approximately(!) $\frac{9-d}8$.
The probability that $a$ is divisible by $d$ is approximately(!) $\frac1d$ and is almost(!) independant of whether or not $a$ is $\ge d\cdot 111\ldots1$.
The probability that, if $a$ is indeed divisible by $d$, the number $\frac ad$ has no zeroes is at most $1$; in fact for $d>1$ it looks like it decreases $\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore we estimate the expected number of zero-free $n$-digit divisors of $a$ as approximately (and likely less than) 
$$\sum_{d=1}^9 \frac{9-d}{8}\cdot\frac1d=\frac{4609}{2240}\approx 2.06$$
and hence get $$\tag1p(n)\approx \frac{2.06}{9^n}.$$
For small $n$, this estimate as quite a bit off. For example, it gives $p(1)\approx0.2286$ instead of the correct value $p(1)=\frac{23}{81}=0.28395\ldots$, next $p(2)\approx 0.0254$ instead of $p(2)=\frac{163}{6561}=0.02484\ldots$, and next $p(3)\approx 0.00282$ instead of $p(3)=\frac{483}{177147}=0.00261\ldots$. However, we observe already here (though only empirically!) that the estimate $(1)$ is an upper bound for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Wow very nice and thorough analysis! Thanks a lot. I have a question: near the end you indicate exact values of $p(1), p(2), p(3)$. Did you find these values using computer?

Comment: There is a small typo: $p(1)=\frac{23}{81}$ rather than $p(1)=\frac{32}{81}$. The counts of n-digit zero-free division pairs (obtained by computer) go as follows: 23, 163, 1389, 12070, 105206, 918479, 8029604, 70289783, 616094735. As predicted by Hagen von Eitzen, the actual counts are lower than the estimate (1) and the difference grows with growing $n$ (i.e. $9^n\times p(n)$ gets smaller and smaller).

Comment: @Prism Yes, these were found by brute-force counting. More early terms of the sequence can be calculated like that, but it takes longer and longer and gets more and more boring.